# How do you count up each string value for each year?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Trying to figure out how to count each crime for each year to see which years the most crimes occurred, using MySQL

This code is giving me the number of times each distinct crime is happening per year.

```
SELECT year_time, offense_category, COUNT(*) AS crime_incidents
FROM rms_crime_incidents
GROUP BY year_time, offense_category
ORDER BY year_time DESC, offense_category ASC, crime_incidents ASC;
```

I want the total number of crimes per year.

These are my current results

```
    year_time   offense_category    crime_incidents
    2022            AGGRAVATED ASSAULT  14
    2022            DAMAGE TO PROPERTY  7
    2022            OBSTRUCTING JUDICIARY   2
    2021            AGGRAVATED ASSAULT  443
    2021            BURGLARY            204
    2021            DAMAGE TO PROPERTY  460
    2021            DANGEROUS DRUGS         59
    2021            DISORDERLY CONDUCT  14
```

I am expecting

```
        year_time   total_crime_incidents
    2022            140
    2022            789
    2022            254
    2021            443
    2021            204
    2021            460
    2021            590
    2021            126
```

Sample data:
[image: SAMPLE DATA]

Comment: Just use SUM instead of COUNT? Please provide some sample data.

Comment: How do any of those numbers relate? Your expected results has the same number of rows as the current results, but with some numbers the same and others changed.

Comment: This is all test data, the numbers expected are not real. Hence they look similar to my current result. I've added a small snippet of what the data looks like (omitting, unrelated columns) @dc-ddfe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the `offense_category` from the `select` list and the `group by` clause so the query only groups by year:

```sql
SELECT   year_time, COUNT(*) AS total_crime_incidents
FROM     rms_crime_incidents
GROUP BY year_time
ORDER BY year_time DESC
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH Mureinik, I would upvote but I need at least 15 reputation...